Can you arbitrarily define your sample space?
Let's say you flip a fair coin. A sample space is a set of possible outcomes of an experiment. So, intuitively, the sample space will be {Head, Tail}.
However, I have seen that it is also possible to set the sample space like below. I think that Head corresponds to $\left( -\infty ,0 \right)$ and Tail does to $\left[ 0,\infty  \right)$. Why is this allowed? Assuming it is allowed, what would be rules when you arbitrarily define your sample space?
$\Omega = \{ \left( -\infty ,0 \right),\left[ 0,\infty  \right) \} = R$

Conventionally, the only mathematical constraint on the sample space is that it is a set.

If you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F , P)$ then you need all the elements of the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ to be subsets of the sample space $\Omega$ but there are no substantial constraints on $\Omega$ beyond that.

Usually the sample space is indicated by the problem you confront and how you conceptualize it.  What is "allowed" is far more general: there's nobody policing how you think about and model your situation.  I suspect your second formulation arises by first defining a random variable and then determining the smallest sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R$ for which it is measurable.

Of course, some sample spaces are easier to work with than others; in your example, calculating the probability of two heads using a mathematical expression (i.e., a probability distribution) is not as simple as if the sample space is ${0,1}$.

You claim you have seen a sample space where the heads is derived as a subset of real values, and the tails complementary. I'm curious where you have "seen" this? And I'm curious in what way it is "arbitrary" to you.
